# recursive function return different values depending of order when summing array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, sum, element

I implemented the following recursive JS function to get the the sum of elements in a array. This function works fine, when input [1,2,3] it returns 6, which is OK.

```
function sumOfNumbers(array) {
    if (array.length == 1) {
        return array[0];
    } else {
        last = array.length - 1;
        return array[last] + sumOfNumbers(array.slice(0, last));
    }
}
```

However, when changing the order of the sum to:

```
    return sumOfNumbers(array.slice(0,last)) + array[last];
```

It returns 5 for [1,2,3]. Does anybody knows why?

Comment: Why are you doing this recursively anyway? Wasted memory, just use a loop.

Comment: Nit, I am studing recursivity algorithms

Answer (score 3):

Because the variable `last` is global, and you're changing it with your call to `sumOfNumbers(array.slice(0,last))`, before this part: `array[last]` sees it.

Comment: It is actually true, thank you! I changed to var last and works well in any order.